# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' after adding applicationinsights

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights, modulenotfounderror, async-hooks

```
Error: ./node_modules/cls-hooked/context.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'
```

After adding the applicationinsights package, I am getting the above error in my application.

I have added it by using this syntax `require('applicationinsights')`. I believe the problem lies in the `require` keyword. I tried every other internet answer related to this error but nothing worked.

Comment: What version of Angular u are using? You are not using TS import? 
I am using Angular 12, and i use import as like this

import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';

Comment: No, I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights. Is it possible to show data in the Live Metrics(Azure Portal) by using @microsoft/applicationinsights-web?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use node.js appInsights. You have to use Angular's AppInsights package in Angular refer the below article

[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/#:~:text=Step%202%20%E2%80%93%20Configure%20Angular%20application%20and%20include%20dependencies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/#:%7E:text=Step%202%20%E2%80%93%20Configure%20Angular%20application%20and%20include%20dependencies)

Comment: But I need to log Live Metrics in Azure. Is it possible to do with the above approach?